# Implementing iAd using Singleton Class

Tags: objective-c, ios4, iad

I am new to iPhone development. My objective is to implement a singleton class for iAd, so that I share the single instance of iAd over multiple view controllers?

Any help on the implementation side will be much appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your AppDelegate.h

```
@property (assign) YouiAdClass*iADObject    
+ (AppDelegate*) sharedApplication;
+ (YouriAdClass*)sharedAd
```

In your AppDelegate.m

```
@synthesize iADObject

+ (AppDelegate*) sharedApplication
{
    return [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}

+(YouriAdClass*)sharedAd
{
    if(iAdObject==nil){
          iADObject=[YouriAdClass new]
   }
   return iADObject;
}
```

Now when you want to get your object in any place just call

```
YouriADClass*iadObject=[[AppDelegate sharedApplication] sharedAd];
```

And you will get always the same pointer.
Remember to import AppDelegate andYouriADClass in your header files.

Comment: If I donot include this code in an App Delegate instead create it as seperate class and then call it. Would it create problem then? I think it is still creating a shared instance.

Comment: In order of doing that, just check the iOS doc. Lookup how to create a singleton instance in ios.