# Shared iAD over different ViewControllers

Tags: objective-c, ios, iad

I have 3 ViewControllers that I would like to share the same iAD. I have read the documentation and sharing the iAD seems to be the proper way to implement iAD into your project. What is the best way to accomplish this? I am newer to Objective C so as detailed as you could be is appreciated.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a singleton class?  Check this out, it might help.. [Implementing iAd using Singleton Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017759/implementing-iad-using-singleton-class)